# Exported variable vs exported function in a DLL

Tags: windows, dll, portable-executable, dllexport

How to know if the exported symbol from a `dll` is actually `variable` or a `function` ?

One way may be to look whether the destination address of the symbol resides in the `.code` section or not.
Another method could be to check the [memory protection attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366786%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the selected section.

But all these methods seem to be unreliable.

What is the best way ?

Comment: This squarely falls in the "if you don't know then you should not be using this" category.  Contact the owner of the DLL for support.

Comment: @HansPassant Unfortunately, I needed this to do as I was writing a tool which will detect inline api hooks in an executing process. For this I traversed over the export directory of each loaded module, checking which exported symbol differs from their file on disk. Hence I need to know which exports are api and which are variables. Otherwise, there will be a lot of false positives.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't make a lot of sense.  No way to hook a variable so the value is always correct.  After correcting for relocation anyway.